# How to programmatically change position of a button with refrence to other button using autolayout contraints?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using a tableview in which there are three buttons. if one button get hide eg. second button gets hide then the third button should take place of second button. Like that if first button hides then the second and third button should also shift so as to fill the empty space of first button.

Comment: Are you placed three buttons in single row of tableView?What is your prototype structure? please elaborate your qus

Comment: All three buttons are side by side in a single row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the following Steps:
1-Do Auto Layout of all button as you want.Make Outlet of contraints that are relative to buttons i.e make outlet contraints of second button which touches the first button etc.
2-When you want to hide the first button, Hide it and write the following code:

```
 NmaeOfOutletofContraints.constant=amountofgapYouWantBetweenButtons;
```

3-In you .h file make outlet as below:

```
 IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *ContraintOutlet;
```

Answer (score 0):

on hiding the button other buttons taking up its place has nothing to do with whether you place it in tableView, Cell or on View. In all the cases underlying idea to deal with is same.

Multiple ways of doing it. I'll show you 3 ways each comes with its own issues and benefits, select the once which suits you.

**Method 1: Create IBOutlets to Constraints and change their constants value**

Create a IBOutlet to to buttons width and trailing constraints and when you need to hide the button simply set the button's width constraint to 0 and also optionally set the trailing space from it to the button behind it to 0 as well.

[image]

[image]

Finally when you need to hide button 2, simply say

```
    self.button2WidthConstraint.constant = 0
    self.button2TrailingConstarint.constant = 0
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Do the same for all buttons and deal with them.

**Issue :**

Buttons have intrinsic size, setting the width constraints on buttons width will override the intrinsic size. That means if your button title changes dynamically and the width u set to button isn't sufficient to accommodate that it will truncate the button title.

Not a great idea!!!

**Method 2: Take the benefit of constraint's priority value.**

Method 1 expects you to create 2 IBOutlets for each button and also runs into a issue of overriding button's intrinsic size. Method2 solves it.

Drag a horizontal spacing constraint from button 1 to button 3 and change its priority to High and set the constant to 8

[image]

[image]

Now when you want to hide button2 simply remove it from superview using

```
self.button2.removeFromSuperview()
```

How it works ?

Simple you have specified that the distance between button3 and button1 should be 8pt but because the constraint isn't required it won't come into action as long as other required constraints helps iOS calculating buttons frame.

But once u remove button2 all the constraints added to it will also be removed so the existing required constraints are not sufficient so the high priority constraint of yours kicks in and manages the space.

Clean and Elegant solution. No IBOutlets to constraints.

Pros :

Clean and Elegant solution. No IBOutlets to constraints.

Cons :

Because you remove the button2 completely all the constraint added to it will also be remove :( So if you want to bring it back to view at some point you will have to programmatically create the constraints to it and apply it.

**Method 3: Lets fix the issue with Method 1**

Issue with method 1 was that it was overriding the button's intrinsic size which is a problem. Lets fix it with constraint's priority value :)

This time apply width constraint to button two but make the constraint priority as high rather than required and set the constant as 0.

[image]

Because width constraint is just a high priority it will not come into action until its necessary. So iOS will honor the button's intrinsic size.

But when you need to hide the button change the constraint's priority to high. Thats all.

```
self.button2WidthConstraint.priority = 1000
```

Pros :

Will honor button's intrinsic size.

Cons :

Expects you to create multiple IBOutlets each button one for width and one for trailing constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by 2 ways

1. Adjusting constraints between buttons.
2. Simply create 3 proto type cells which has 1,2 & 3 buttons.Reload
   your row when ever to need.

Comment: Three Prototype cell simply hiding button seriously? Any idea how many combinations you will end up creating ? Strict no